# For positive real numbers $x,y,z$, Prove that

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, jensen-inequality

> For positive real numbers $x,y,z$, Prove that,
>
> $$\bigg(\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x+y+z}\bigg)^{(x+y+z)}\geq x^xy^yz^z \geq
>  \bigg(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\bigg)^{(x+y+z)}$$

I have no idea how to begin this? I am getting a hint  for A.M. - G.M. equality but numbers don't seem to fit.

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Stacy: Where did you see this problem ? in a magazine ? a book or a homework. Which class you are taking that the Prof. assigned this problem? it's interesting.

Comment: @DeepSea This was problem in an assignment given by our professor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

> Try using $x$ times $x$, $y$ times $y$ , $z$ times $z$.

**EDIT:**

> Seemingly people downvote hints so updating the full solution.

---

Using A.M. - G.M. inequality,

$$\frac{x+x+..(x \;\Bbb{times})+y+y+..(y \;\Bbb{times})+z+z+..(z \;\Bbb{times})}{x+y+z}\geq (x^xy^yz^z)^{\frac{1}{x+y+Z}}$$

$$\bigg(\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x+y+z}\bigg)^{(x+y+z)}\geq x^xy^yz^z $$

Using G.M. - H.M. inequality,

$$(x^xy^yz^z)^{\frac{1}{x+y+Z}} \geq \frac{x+y+z}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x}+..(x \; \Bbb{times})+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{y}+..(y \; \Bbb{times})+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z}+..(z \; \Bbb{times})}$$

$$ x^xy^yz^z \geq
 \bigg(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\bigg)^{(x+y+z)}$$

$$\bigg(\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x+y+z}\bigg)^{(x+y+z)}\geq x^xy^yz^z \geq
 \bigg(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\bigg)^{(x+y+z)}$$

Comment: How did you type the answer that fast? You posted the answer within $2$ minutes the question was posted

Comment: @tienlee copied authors notation and I work on a PC so.

Comment: What does mean $\pi$ times?

Comment: Better to just refer to the Weighted AM-GM Inequality.  As @user108128, "$\pi$ copies of $\pi$" does not really mean much.

Comment: @user108128 just to quantify the number of terms, nothing more.

Comment: Is there a special approach for such problems? How do you know what combination of terms will really work?

Answer (score 4):

Since $\ln$ is a concave function we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{x+y+z}\ln{x}\leq\ln\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{x+y+z}\cdot x\right)=\ln\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x+y+z},$$
which gives a left inequality.

The right inequality it's just Jensen for the convex function $f(x)=x\ln{x}:$
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}x\ln{x}}{3}\geq\frac{x+y+z}{3}\ln\frac{x+y+z}{3}.$$